# Drawing a bar plot - ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to draw a bar plot from a dataframe and I am getting the ValueError from the final line. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here's my code:

```
#Calculate sparsity per day
grouped_id = df_sample.set_index('id', drop=False, inplace=False)
grouped_id = grouped_id.groupby('id')

df = grouped_id['avg_sparsity'].agg(np.sum).to_frame()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['avg_sparsity'] = df['avg_sparsity'].apply(lambda x: int(x)/unique_time_cnt)                                                         
df['color'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: 'r' if x in h_ids else 'y' )
df['type'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: 'h' if x in h_ids else 'c')
df['fid'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: fid_map.get(x))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,7), dpi=100)

plt.bar( left=df['fid'], height=df['avg_sparsity'], color=df['color'])
```

Comment: What about `plt.bar( left=df['fid'].values, height=df['avg_sparsity'].values, color=df['color'].values)` ?

Comment: @jezrael It returns the same error if I change the code.

Comment: Are you sure last row return error? My answer does not works too?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need convert columns to numpy arrays by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and colors also to `list`:

```
plt.bar(left=df['fid'].values, 
        height=df['avg_sparsity'].values,
        color=df['color'].values.tolist())
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fid' : [2,4,5],
                   'avg_sparsity' : [10,20,30],
                   'color':['r','y','y']})

print (df)                   
   avg_sparsity color  fid
0            10     r    2
1            20     y    4
2            30     y    5

plt.bar(left=df['fid'].values, 
        height=df['avg_sparsity'].values.tolist(), 
        color=df['color'].values.tolist())
```

[image: graph]